# How to send log on parameters to get wsdl

Tags: .net, web-services, wsdl

I have url of my wsdl file which opens in browser by giving username and password.How can i provide username and password to that wsdl pragmatically to get that wsdl in xml format.Following is the code for reference.

```
    class Program    {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
                  WebServiceInfo webServiceInfo =        WebServiceInfo.OpenWsdl("https://xyz.com/partners?wsdl");

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("WebService: {0}", webServiceInfo.Url));
```

}

```
        public class WebServiceInfo
        {
           WebMethodInfoCollection _webMethods = new WebMethodInfoCollection();
           Uri _url;
           static Dictionary<string, WebServiceInfo> _webServiceInfos =
               new Dictionary<string, WebServiceInfo>();

           private WebServiceInfo(Uri url)
           {
               if (url == null)
                   throw new ArgumentNullException("url");
               _url = url;
               _webMethods = GetWebServiceDescription(url);
           }

           public static WebServiceInfo OpenWsdl(string url)
           {
               Uri uri = new Uri(url);
               return OpenWsdl(uri);
           }
      }
```

Thanks

Comment: The answer depends on what sort of authentication the app is doing.  One way you might be able to tell - Are you authenticating inside a web page, or does it pop up a little window?  Also, once you're authenticated, are there any cookies sent along with your requests?  You can tell if you [run Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/).

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham:i want to authenticate that in console application and get the xml format of wsdl

Comment: That doesn't tell me what type of authentication the web application requires.  It sounds like you don't know, which is going to make this problem harder to solve.  Use fiddler and learn about the difference between authenticated calls (ones that let you see the WSDL) and unauthenticated calls (ones that bring up the login prompt).  Do textual diffs on them and see what is different between those two types of calls.  Maybe some type of cookie is sent along with your request.

Answer (score 0):

[assumingit's Windows Authentication we're talking about...]

System.Net.Credentials provides facilities for that, can't test it right now but this should be near to what you need to do:

```
//request object provided for reference purposes
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://url");
//add the following
request.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but its giving me error like 'The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.' in following code  
                  'webRequest.Credentials = new   System.Net.NetworkCredential("abc","lmn");
                                
                   System.Net.WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse();'